# Losing surface texture after decimate

Tags: mesh, uv, texture-baking

I am a complete noob when it comes to blender and manipulating 3d objects in general, so please forgive my ignorance.

What I'm trying to do is import a 3d model into Tabletop Simulator.  I have a wavefront .obj model that I would like to import, and based on tutorials I have watched, used "decimate" to reduce the number of triangles in the model, since Tabletop seems to only support about 7 or 8 thousand "Tris."

The model is apparently ginormous*, because Tabletop Simulator won't even try to load it unless I scale it way down and then decimate it. Once I complete the decimate operation, setting the ratio to about .06, I lose a lot of the surface area of the model.  I end up with a model that has a large portion reduced to a "mesh" without any actual surface texture.  I am able to import the model into Tabletop Simulator, but the "mesh" portion is missing.  The model is missing body parts.

From other tutorials, I think I have to unwrap the "UV" (somehow) and then "bake" (somehow) a new texture on to the mesh.  Unfortunately, the tutorial I was using as a guide uses an old version of Blender, and the interface for 2.8 is completely different. The fact that I barely understand the lingo doesn't help much, LOL!

Anyway, if anyone has the time (or patience) to point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance,

Tim

*The wavefront model I am using was created was exported by "Cura" which I have been using with my 3d printer. I purchased the model from Heroforge.